# Excel lookup assistance

Tags: excel, vba, lookup

I have data in column `A` and I will past data into column `B`, if there is a match I would like it to copy and paste the matching code into column `C`. So far I have `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,B:B, 0)), "No Match", "Match")`.

But this only partially helps. If there is a match, i would like it to paste the code that matches, and if possible in order too (For example, if `A3` and `B7` match, it writes Match in `C7`, I like if it pasted the information in `C1` for the first match, then `C2` for the second match).

Comment: Your intent is a little unclear. Can you give us a diagram of what you want it to look like?

Comment: Seems perfectly clear to me

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with one helper column.

Column A: helper

Column B and C: columns with your data

Column D: output

```
A1: =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,C:C,0)),0,1)
A2: =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B2,C:C,0)),A1,A1+1)
A3: =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B3,C:C,0)),A2,A2+1), etc. 

D1: =VLOOKUP(ROW(D1),A:C,2,FALSE)
D2: =VLOOKUP(ROW(D2),A:C,2,FALSE), etc.
```

Column A has to go on the left of the other two, due to the limitation of VLOOKUP. It'll list matching entries in the order they appear in B, followed by #N/A's. If you want them in the order they are in C, just do MATCH(C1, B:B) instead of MATCH(B1, C:C), etc.